# How do I save selected sequences in seqkit to a file?

Tags: seqkit

Consider:

> seqkit grep -nrp ";s__nosocomialis;"  ribogrove_11.217_sequences.fasta

Using this command lets me select all sequences related to the organism "*A. nosocomialis*" in the [RiboGrove](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35217168/) database.

How do I save these selected sequences to a new ".fasta" file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [the docs](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/seqkit/usage/#grep), seqkit grep has a `-o` "output file" option, so if you get the correct output with:

```
seqkit grep -nrp ";s__nosocomialis;" ribogrove_11.217_sequences.fasta
```

Then this command will (in theory) give you your desired outcome:

```
seqkit grep -nrp ";s__nosocomialis;" ribogrove_11.217_sequences.fasta -o new.fasta
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I don't know how i didn't see the output command while surfing the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For any program that prints output to the terminal (standard output), you can always redirect to a file using `>` or `>>`. Either of the two will create the output file if it doesn't exist, but `>` will overwrite any contents of an already existing file, while `>>` will append to it without overwriting. So you could just do:

```
seqkit grep -nrp ";s__nosocomialis;" ribogrove_11.217_sequences.fasta > out.fa
```